# Run my script more than one time

Tags: powershell

This powershell can just copy one time, but iIed to put a variable to do it `x` times, for example (`$copy_this = 8`). I don't know witch command to use.

```
$from ='C:\Users\\Desktop\'
$to = 'C:\Users\\Desktop\' + [datetime]::Today.ToString('yyyyMMdd')
Copy-Item $from -Destination $to -Recurse
Rename-Item -Path $to -NewName "$(Get-Random)"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a single step in you script to be done multiple times you can do that with loops. In your particular case I would recommend a "while loop"

I'll give you a basic example:

```
$n = 0

While($n -lt 10)
{
Copy-Item -Path $Source -Destination $Target
$n++
}
```

To better understand the concept of loops please also see this link: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/4542.powershell-loops.aspx

In addition:This is a fairly simple resolution, and it would have been achieved by a simple google search.
Please also see  the guide to "How to ask a good question" https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask

Good Luck with your scripting.